# Different answer between HeatTransferPDEComponent and Matlab

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, heat-equation

I've been working on a 2-layer HeatTransferPDE Model.
The diagram of the model is
[image: model]

The two materials have an initial temperature of 37℃, and the outside is 75℃. The model is for heat insulation so it can simplify to a one-dimensional HeatTransferPDE.

Mathematica codes are:

```
outsideTemp = 273.15 + 75;
boundary1 = 0.6/1000;
boundary2 = (0.6 + 6)/1000;
Ω1 = Line[{{0}, {boundary1}}];
Ω2 = Line[{{boundary1}, {boundary2}}];
vars = {T[t, x], t, {x}};

pars1 = <|"ThermalConductivity" -> 0.082, "AmbientTemperature" -> 273.15 + 37, "Density" -> 300, "SpecificHeatCapacity" -> 1377|>;

B1 = HeatTransferValue[x == 0, vars, <|"HeatTransferCoefficient" -> 114, "AmbientTemperature" -> outsideTemp|>];
pde1 = {HeatTransferPDEComponent[vars, pars1] == B1, T[0, x] == 273.15 + 37};
Tfun1 = NDSolveValue[pde1, T, {t, 0, 100}, {x} ∈ Ω1];

pars2 = <|"ThermalConductivity" -> 0.37, "Density" -> 862, "SpecificHeatCapacity" -> 2100, "SurfaceTemperature" -> Tfun1[t, boundary1]|>;
B2 = HeatTemperatureCondition[x == boundary1, vars, pars2];
pde2 = {HeatTransferPDEComponent[vars, pars2] == 0, B2, T[0, x] == 273.15 + 37};
Tfun2 = NDSolveValue[pde2, T, {t, 0, 100}, {x}∈ Ω2];

Plot3D[{Tfun1[t, x], Tfun2[t, x]}, {t, 0, 100}, {x, 0, boundary2}, PlotRange -> All]
```

The output is

[image: Temperature with time]

However, I use finite difference with same parameters and the output is
[image: Temperature with time(0 to 100) in matlab]

The matlab code is too long to put in here(because it's for a 4-layer model).

I checked the code for a day and still have no clue why there is a difference between them, the material properties is in the table below.

[image: material properties table]

Thanks!

Comment: I see two problems. First, this is a coupled problem, and you cannot solve PDEs separately. Instead, define variable material parameters, such as: ``\[Lambda]1 = 0.082;
\[Lambda]2 = 0.37; \[Lambda] = (\[Lambda]2 - \[Lambda]1) HeavisideTheta[x - boundary1] + \[Lambda]1;`` and then use ``"ThermalConductivity" -> \[Lambda]`` for the _whole_ region ``{x} \[Element] Line[{{0}, {boundary2}}]``. Secondly, where did the parameter ``"HeatTransferCoefficient" -> 114`` come from? Are you intentionally modelling convention? If you lower this, the solution looks less steep.

Comment: @Domen The HeatTransferCoefficient is calculated by Matlab and I want to verify it in Mathematica. Thanks for your advice, I will rewrite my code to see if it works or not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two models based on FEM we can test for this problem. First, standard FEM with  mesh of 6600 line elements

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];

boundary2 = (0.6 + 6)/1000; reg = Line[{{0}, {boundary2}}]; mesh = 
 ToElementMesh[reg, MaxCellMeasure -> 10^-6]
```

Define parameters and solution

```
rho[x_] := If[x <= .6/1000, 300, 862]; 
c[x_] := If[x <= .6/1000, 1377, 2100]; 
a[x_] := If[x <= .6/1000, .082, .37];
eq = rho[x] c[x] D[T[t, x], t] - D[a[x] T[t, x], x, x] == 0;
ic = T[0, x] == 37; bc = T[t, 0] == 75; sol = 
 NDSolveValue[{eq, ic, bc}, T, {t, 0, 100}, Element[{x}, mesh]]
```

This solution not looks like Matlab FDM solution

```
Plot3D[sol[t, x], {t, 0, 100}, {x, 0, .0066}, Mesh -> None, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Second solution is based on FEM, but with some new functions introduced in v.12.2

```
vars = {T[t, x], t, {x}};boundary2 = (0.6 + 6)/1000; reg = Line[{{0}, {boundary2}}];
pars = <|"ThermalConductivity" -> a[x], "MassDensity" -> rho[x], 
  "SpecificHeatCapacity" -> c[x], 
  "SurfaceTemperature" -> 
   75|>; pde = {HeatTransferPDEComponent[vars, pars] == 0, 
  HeatTemperatureCondition[x == 0, vars, pars], T[0, x] == 37};
Tfun = NDSolveValue[pde, T, {t, 0, 100}, {x} \[Element] reg];
```

This solution also differs from that fined out with FDM, but looks similar to `sol` shown above

```
Plot3D[Tfun[t, x], {t, 0, 100}, {x, 0, .0066}, Mesh -> None, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

[image: Figure 2]

We can compare two solutions in one point `t=100`

```
Plot[{sol[100, x], Tfun[100, x]}, {x, 0, .0066}]
```

[image: Figure 3]

The question is why they differ? To answer this question we can check the number of line elements used to compute  `Tfun`

```
Tfun["ElementMesh"]

Out[]= ElementMesh[{{0., 0.0066}}, {LineElement["<" 20 ">"]}]
```

Therefore, the mesh of 20 line elements has been used to compute solution `Tfun` while for `sol` we defined `mesh` of 6600 line elements.

Comment: Great answer.  Thanks for the detailed explanation.  To learn about this, I ran the second part that you list and must be doing something wrong.  It throws an error: ```NDSolveValue::deqn: Equation or list of equations expected instead of ...```  Maybe one of the listed variables is defined in code you didn't post?  For example, is vars defined somewhere?

Comment: Sorry, `vars` is defined in your post. I have added definitions of `reg` and `vars` to the code.

Comment: I had missed it in the OP - thanks for adding.  Now everything works as I expect.  Cheers!

Comment: Is there a way to increase the number of line elements using the second method?  I've tried several methods and nothing seems to change.

Comment: We can use `mesh` from standard FEM approach  `Tfun = NDSolveValue[pde, T, {t, 0, 100}, {x} \[Element] mesh];`